# Is there way to optimize snap-to-object algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

So I have n objects that can be dragged on a stage and I want them to snap (lock, magnet...) to each other when you drag them close enough. That means calculating the distance from dragged object to every other object on the stage on every mouse move event. Can this be optimized? Something like comparing the distance only to the closes objects but how do I know which are the closes without calculating all distances first?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). K-d tree has an efficient "find closest neighbor" function. Just make sure each object which is already 'in place' is in your tree, and when you move an element - find its closest neighbor, and check if it is close enough or not.

---

An alternative (mostly usable for grids) is using [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Whenever you place an object - draw the line where its 'influence' starts. Attach each 'cell' on this line with an observer, and when you are moving an object to a cell, if it has any observers attached to it - invoke them.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

1. You could divide your stage into 'tiles' of some size (say, 64x64 pixels?). If you knew which tiles would overlap (partially or completely) a given tile, you could limit your hit detection to those.
2. You could maintain a (sorted!) map which maps a given 'y' coordinate to all the object(s) on that 'y' position. Each list of objects at the `y` coordinate is sorted as well, giving the objects sorted by their X order. By using the lower/upper bound (which is efficient to compute on sorted sequences) you could quickly get handles to all objects within a certain bounding rect.

Answer (score 1):

On classical solution to this kind of problems is to cut the space recursively into areas. You only search neigboors in close areas. A classical data structure for this is [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) where square are cut into four squares.